# Moifying Netlogo extension API in Java

Tags: javascript, netlogo

I am trying to modify an existing netlogo extension which is written in Java. I am new to programming, and want to ask if classes can be modified (using eclipse) or i have to create a new extension altogether.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Are the modifications you are making to the java source code? If so, it will need to be recompiled and packaged into a new jar file.  I use NetBeans, but Eclipse should work just as well.

Comment: If you are new to programming, making or modifying NetLogo extensions is a very difficult task to start with. That doesn't mean you will necessarily, but you should be aware that there is a great deal you will need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to take an existing extension and modify it.

It it also possible to build new extensions from scratch.

The documentation is here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API